# Parse/ tree diagram for phrasal constituents of a specific sentence

Tags: parsing, syntax, tree, linguistics

I'm trying to do some language analysis on the opening paragraph of The Kite Runner by Khaled Hosseini, specifically looking at phrasal constituents. The first sentence is as follows:

"I became what I am today at the age of twelve, on a frigid overcast day in the winter of 1975."

I've got a pretty good idea of what the phrasal constituents are, but I'm a bit unsure as to how to draw the tree, as it seems like the tree should be split into two distinct branches, splitting at the comma after twelve. I've uploaded an image [my tree so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp5Kw.png), but I'm not sure if it's correct or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called `constituent-treelib` that can be used to construct, process and visualize constituent trees. First, we must install the library:

`pip install constituent-treelib`

Then, we can use it as follows to parse the sentence into a constituent tree, visualize it, and finally export the result to a PDF file:

```py
from constituent_treelib import ConstituentTree

# Define a sentence
sentence = "You must construct additional pylons!"

# Define the language that should be considered 
language = ConstituentTree.Language.English
spacy_model_size = ConstituentTree.SpacyModelSize.Medium

# Construct the neccesary NLP pipeline by downloading and installing the required models (benepar and spaCy)
nlp = ConstituentTree.create_pipeline(language, spacy_model_size, download_models=True)

# Instantiate a ConstituentTree object and pass it both the sentence and the NLP pipeline
tree = ConstituentTree(sentence, nlp)

# Export the visualization of the tree into a PDF file
tree.export_tree('my_constituent_tree.pdf')
```

The result...

[image: (S (NP (PRP You)) (VP (MD must) (VP (VB construct) (NP (JJ additional) (NNS pylons)))) (. !))]